# Ajax call in Core PHP,

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

in one of my front end PHP files im doing this in my Jquery :

```
var name = $('#core_name').val();
var param = {};
        param['name'] = name;
        $.ajax({
            url:'../back_end/user.php/verify_name',
            data:param,
            type:'POST',
            success:function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

In my back_end/user.php im doing this :

```
<?php
class User{

    function index(){
        //for now do nothing  
    }
    function verify_name(){
        echo "here";        
    }
}
?>
```

Why cant i alert "here", what is it that iam doing wrong ?
Firebug detects no error , so the file user.php has correct path (no 404 error) why cant i reach the function verify_name ?

Comment: what PHP framework are you using?

Comment: @SDC , core php , no framework used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `User` class and call `verify_name()` on `back_end/user.php`.

You can do this adding the following to `back_end/user.php`:

```
$user = new User;
$user->verify_name();
```